# Como crear un binary search sobre un archivo en SCALA

Tags: scala

Buenos dias a todos, 
Tengo el siguiente archivo:

```
10,44,22
10,47,12
15,38,3
15,41,30
16,44,15
16,47,18
22,38,21
22,41,42
34,44,40
34,47,36
40,38,39
40,41,42
45,38,27
45,41,30
46,44,45
46,47,48
```

Sobre este archivo quiero hacer diferentes consultas, por ejemplo traigame los valores que tengan las filas (x,44,y) entonces el programa me trae 10,44,22; 16,44,15; 34,44,40; 46,44,45, una vez obtenida las filas separar las variables x,y luego me trae 10,22;16,15;34,40;46,45. Para esto hice un programa que me lee todo el archivo y a medida que va encontrando los numeros le pongo un condicional para que me almacene el valor x,y en un vector:

```
        val in = newScanner("patSPO.csv")
        val con:convst = new convst()
        var yi:Int = 0
        val nodey:Value = Val(y).value
        yi=con.convN2I(nodey.name)
        while (scannerHasNext(in)) {
          val s  = in.nextt(',')
          val p = in.nextt(',')
          val o  = in.nextt('\n')
          if (p == yi) {
            val fields:Fields = Vector(s,o)

          }
        }
```

Mi problema en este momento es que tengo que leer todo el archivo cada vez que quiero hacer una consulta, y esto para archivos muy grandes toma mucho tiempo, 
Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de subir este archivo a memoria com por ejemplo un Map (ListMap, Collection, TreeMap) el cual me permita hacer las consultas de una manera mas rapida, y que no tenga que consultar el archivo cada vez que lo necesite?

Answer (score 0):

Un modo muy cómodo es usando `case classes`:

```
case class Terna(x,y,z)
```

Construimos una secuencia de estas ternas:

```
import scala.io.Source

val f = Source.fromFile("patSPO.csv")

val ternasIt = for {
  line <- f.getLines
  Array(a,b,c) = line.split(",").map(_.toInt)
} yield Terna(a,b,c)
val ternas = ternasIt.toSeq
```

Y a partir de aquí a operar. Siguiendo el ejemplo que pones, para traer las ternas del tipo `Ternas(_,44,_)`:

```
val res = ternas collect { case Terna(x,44,z) => (x,z) }
```